# How to fix a SVG Glyph with wrong position and size?

Tags: html, css, svg, glyph

I have a SVG file with many icons:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN""http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<metadata>Generated by Fontastic.me</metadata>
<defs>
<font id="myfont" horiz-adv-x="512">
<font-face font-family="myfont" units-per-em="512" ascent="480" descent="-32"/>
<missing-glyph horiz-adv-x="512" />

<glyph glyph-name="cap-table" unicode="&#97;" d="M426 227c-10-85-82-152-170-152-94 0-171 77-171 171 0 87 60 162 155 169l0-187z m-159 215c94 0 171-76 171-170 0-7-1-14-1-20l-170 0c0 0 0 190 0 190z"/>
<glyph glyph-name="cap-hamburger" unicode="&#98;" d="M378 319l-244 0c-15 0-27 12-27 27 0 15 12 27 27 27l244 0c15 0 27-12 27-27 0-15-12-27-27-27z m0-90l-244 0c-15 0-27 12-27 27 0 15 12 27 27 27l244 0c15 0 27-12 27-27 0-15-12-27-27-27z m0-91l-244 0c-15 0-27 13-27 27 0 15 12 27 27 27l244 0c15 0 27-12 27-27 0-14-12-27-27-27z"/>
<glyph glyph-name="cap-manage" unicode="&#99;" d="M270 135c-9 0-19 0-28 0-1 1-2 1-3 1-38 5-73 22-104 44-31 21-58 46-83 73 0 2 0 4 0 6 2 2 4 3 6 5 33 35 69 65 111 88 55 30 110 34 166 4 23-12 45-26 66-42 21-17 39-37 59-55 0-2 0-4 0-6-2-2-3-4-5-5-37-39-78-74-128-96-18-8-38-11-57-17z m-14 45c42 0 76 34 76 76 0 43-34 77-76 77-43 0-77-35-77-77 1-42 35-76 77-76z m0 31c-24 0-44 20-45 45 0 25 20 45 45 45 25 0 45-20 45-45 0-24-20-45-45-45z"/>
<glyph glyph-name="cap-my-holdings" unicode="&#100;" d="M157 278l200 0c20 0 37 17 37 38l0 37-50 0 0 25c0 21-16 38-37 38l-100 0c-21 0-37-17-37-38l0-25-50 0 0-37c0-21 17-38 37-38z m38 100c0 7 6 12 12 12l100 0c7 0 12-6 12-12l0-25-124 0z m224-28l0-35c0-34-28-62-62-62l-75 0 0-37c0-7-6-13-13-13l-25 0c-7 0-12 6-12 13l0 37-75 0c-34 0-62 28-62 62l0 35c-14-5-25-19-25-35l0-174c0-21 17-38 38-38l299 0c21 0 37 17 37 38l0 174c0 17-11 31-25 35z"/>
<glyph glyph-name="cap-svb-valuation" unicode="&#72;" d="M60.1,94.1H38L3.1,159.8v17.5h37.4v21.8h19.6v-21.8h10.1v-16.6H60.1V94.1z M40.5,160.7H19.7l20.5-39.9h0.3V160.7z M131.5,105.7c-2.5-4.1-5.9-7-10.1-8.8c-4.2-1.8-9.5-2.7-15.9-2.7c-7.8,0-13.9,1.6-18.3,4.7c-4.4,3.1-7.7,7.3-9.9,12.5 c-2.2,5.2-3.5,11.2-4,17.9c-0.5,6.7-0.7,13.7-0.7,21.1c0,9.3,0.5,17.2,1.6,23.7c1,6.5,2.8,11.7,5.3,15.8c2.5,4.1,5.9,6.9,10.2,8.6 c4.3,1.7,9.5,2.5,15.9,2.5c7.8,0,13.9-1.5,18.3-4.5c4.4-3,7.7-7,9.9-12.2c2.2-5.2,3.5-11.2,4-17.9c0.5-6.7,0.7-13.7,0.7-21.1 c0-9.3-0.5-17.2-1.6-23.7C135.8,115,134,109.8,131.5,105.7z M117,152c0,6.7-0.2,12.4-0.5,16.9c-0.3,4.6-0.9,8.2-1.8,10.9 c-0.8,2.7-2,4.7-3.5,5.8c-1.5,1.1-3.4,1.7-5.8,1.7c-2.3,0-4.2-0.4-5.6-1.3c-1.5-0.9-2.7-2.5-3.6-5c-0.9-2.4-1.5-5.7-1.9-9.9 c-0.3-4.2-0.5-9.6-0.5-16.2v-11.4c0-6.7,0.2-12.4,0.5-16.9c0.3-4.5,0.9-8.2,1.8-10.9c0.8-2.7,2-4.6,3.5-5.8 c1.5-1.1,3.4-1.7,5.8-1.7c2.3,0,4.2,0.4,5.6,1.3c1.5,0.9,2.7,2.5,3.6,5c0.9,2.4,1.5,5.7,1.9,9.9c0.3,4.2,0.5,9.6,0.5,16.2V152z M207.9,143.2c0-6.4-0.3-12.6-1-18.5c-0.7-5.9-2.2-11.2-4.5-15.7c-2.3-4.5-5.7-8.1-10-10.8c-4.4-2.7-10.2-4.1-17.5-4.1 c-11.9,0-20.5,3.2-25.9,9.6c-5.4,6.4-8.1,15.7-8.1,27.9c0,4.7,0.5,9.1,1.4,13.1c0.9,4,2.4,7.5,4.5,10.4c2,2.9,4.7,5.2,7.9,6.8 c3.3,1.6,7.2,2.4,11.9,2.4c4.7,0,8.8-0.8,12.1-2.4c3.3-1.6,5.9-3.8,7.6-6.5h0.3v5c0,3.9-0.1,7.4-0.4,10.7 c-0.3,3.3-0.9,6.1-1.9,8.5c-0.9,2.4-2.3,4.2-3.9,5.6c-1.7,1.3-4,2-6.8,2c-3.6,0-6.1-1.1-7.5-3.3c-1.4-2.2-2.2-5.3-2.2-9.3h-20.5 c0.1,5,1,9.3,2.6,12.7c1.6,3.4,3.8,6.1,6.5,8.2c2.7,2,5.8,3.4,9.3,4.2c3.5,0.7,7.1,1.1,10.9,1.1c8.6,0,15.3-1.6,20.1-4.7 c4.8-3.1,8.3-7.3,10.5-12.7c2.2-5.3,3.6-11.5,4-18.5C207.7,158,207.9,150.7,207.9,143.2z M182.8,144.1c-1.8,3.1-4.8,4.6-9.1,4.6 c-4.2,0-7.1-1.5-8.9-4.6c-1.8-3.1-2.7-8.2-2.7-15.3c0-3,0.1-5.7,0.4-8.2c0.2-2.5,0.8-4.7,1.6-6.6c0.8-1.9,2-3.3,3.5-4.4 c1.5-1,3.6-1.6,6.2-1.6c2.5,0,4.5,0.5,6,1.6c1.5,1,2.7,2.5,3.6,4.3c0.8,1.8,1.4,4,1.7,6.6c0.3,2.6,0.4,5.3,0.4,8.3 C185.5,136,184.6,141.1,182.8,144.1z M257.8,93.2h-26.4l-28,105.9h22.3l4.9-22.4h28.2l4.9,22.4h22.3L257.8,93.2z M234.2,159.3 l10.2-47.6h0.3l10.2,47.6H234.2z"/>
```

Here is how I link with the CSS:

```
@font-face {
font-family: "myfont";
src:url("fonts/myfont.eot");
src:url("fonts/myfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
url("fonts/myfont.woff") format("woff"),
url("fonts/myfont.ttf") format("truetype"),
url("fonts/myfont.svg#myfont") format("svg");
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

And here how I add the content:

```
.cap-icon-table:before {
content: "\61";
}
.cap-icon-hamburger:before {
content: "\62";
}
.cap-icon-manage:before {
content: "\63";
}
.cap-icon-my-holdings:before {
content: "\64";
}
.cap-icon-add-svb-valuation:before {
content: "\48";
}
```

All icons works fine without any issue, my problem is the last glyph that I added (cap-svb-valuation), its a Text SVG and when I add him the browser renders very wrong, small and with inverted rotation.
Im trying to apply CSS properties to fix but without any success.
I cannot read the Icon itself to apply properties. This is how I`m using the icon:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 no-padding">
    <a class="quick-create-option" href="#">
      <span class="cap-icon-add-svb-valuation quick-create-icon"></span>
      <div class="quick-create-option-text">409a Valuations</div>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Is it missing something here? In my head the way to fix this is using CSS properties but I just cannot edit the Icon.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike regular SVGs, the coordinate system for  glyphs is inverted. The Y axis points upward instead of downward.  That means that when you add a glyph to a font, you have to invert the coordinates.

If you are using a tool to create the font, it should do that for you.  If you did it manually then you will need to flip your design in an editor before you copy the `d` attribute across.  There is no way to do it in the font with a `transform` attribute or anything like that.  Although you may be able to do it on the page by flipping the whole pseudo element with a CSS transform.

As to your other complaint about it being two small, that's just the way you've designed it.  If you want it to be wider, scale it upwards. Then add an appropriate `horiz-adv-x` value to the `<glyph>` element.  The default value for the horizontal advance is 512 (defined in the `<font>` element.

So if, for example, you scaled the glyph by 2x, then you would need to add `horiz-adv-x="1024"` (more or less).